# checkbox macro to restrict editing

Tags: excel, debugging, checkbox

The code below is meant to allow only the authoriser (network name "JSMITH") to tick my checkbox so that she confirms she's happy with the report to be sent out (multiple report users but only one authoriser). But I keep getting an error "Object required". What am I doing wrong in the code below? thanks

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()

    If Environ("username") <> "JSMITH" Then
        CheckBox1.Value = False
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I fail to see an obvious issue here. You should probably look at it using the debugger functionality of VBA: http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/debugging.html

Comment: My guess is that you cannot set a checkbox value to false. I would wrap it into an If statement e.g. If CheckBox1.Value = False Then

Comment: I don't understand the last piece of what you are trying to achieve? So if JSMITH is the user and the checkbox is checked, what is supposed to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are after is the following code:

```
Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    If ActiveSheet.Shapes("Check Box 1").ControlFormat.Value = 1 Then
        If Environ("username") = "JSMITH" or Environ("username") = "DTailor" Then
        'Do nothing
        Else
        'Uncheck because user not matching
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("Check Box 1").ControlFormat.Value = 0
        MsgBox ("You are not authorized to tick this box.")
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

For an ActiveX checkbox I would use the following code:

```
Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    If ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("CheckBox1").Object.Enabled = True Then
        If Environ("username") = "JSMITH" or Environ("username") = "DTailor" Then
        'Do nothing
        Else
        'Uncheck because user not matching
        ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("CheckBox1").Object.Enabled = False
        MsgBox ("You are not authorized to tick this box.")
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: what kind of check box do you use? form or activeX?

Comment: My pleasure Elena, glad to help.

Comment: Just updated the code. Don't forget to rate my answer if you like it :)

Comment: There is a green check mark on the left side of the question and an arrow next to the answer that you can use to upvote a answer you liked. Let me know if the updated code works :)

Comment: @elena Just updated the code. Make sure that the name of the checkbox reflected correctly. Btw, if you need urgent help with a non-working code, you can just create a new post on Stack Overflow and there will be usually somebody that will be able to help you pretty quickly.

Comment: Are your ActiveX controls enabled?

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Enable-or-disable-ActiveX-controls-in-Office-documents-cebec41e-b63f-46ac-8961-84dbe0bbd486?CorrelationId=3c36c2f3-1364-4e28-ace6-237c9b0266bb&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&ocmsassetID=HA010031067

Comment: When you record a macro and you check and uncheck that button, what name gets returned?